# How to set and query custom user attributes in Magento?

Tags: database, customer-session, user

I have to generate a report that contains a custom attribute set on the user session.

Here is how the attribute is being set:

```
$customer = Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer();
$customer->setData('mynewattribute', $value )->save();
```

From what I've read, it appears that this value can only be accessed for logged in users. Is that true? Is there no way for me to generate an admin report containing mynewattribute for logged out users? If not, how can I change this code to store the mynewattribute attribute permanently in the database in a way that can be queried, instead of to the session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my problem. I had to add an [install upgrade script](http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-install-install-upgrade-data-and-data-upgrade-scripts/) to add a new attribute to the customer model:

```
#code/local/MYCOMPANY/MYMODULE/sql/mymodule_setup/upgrade-OLDVERSION-NEWVERSION.php
<?php
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

$installer->addAttribute('customer', 'mynewattribute', array(
    'label'     => 'My New Attribute',
    'type'      => 'varchar',
    'input'     => 'text',
    'visible'   => true,
    'required'  => false,
    'adminhtml_only' => '1'
));

Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
    ->getAttribute('customer', 'mynewattribute')
    ->setData('used_in_forms', array('adminhtml_customer'))
    ->save();

$installer->endSetup();
```

Prior to this data upgrade, I believe the value set on the customer model with `$customer->setData('mynewattribute', $value)` was being set for the session duration but didn't persist to the database. Now I can pull the value into reports and use it wherever needed.